# Scaffold description not displaying any text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I ran

```
rails g scaffold Freqs description:string --skip-stylesheets
```

and migrated my database and restarted the server.

When I create a new Freq within my application, it is successfully created, but without any of the text I type into the description box.

I have checked the code in the Freq model, and the description is, indeed, being put out. For some reason it just isn't being displayed.

Any idea why this could be happening? Please request specific code if needed.

Here is the show.html.erb view that corresponds to Freqs:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @freq.description %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_freq_path(@freq) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', freqs_path %>
```

The problem lies within the **controller**. Here is the error I receive when I try to save a description:

WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Freq: description
    app/controllers/freqs_controller.rb:27:in `create'

This is on line 27:

```
@freq = Freq.new(freq_params)
```

I solved the problem by adding

```
attr_accessible :description
```

to the Freq model.

Comment: Can you show the code of the views where that problem is happening?
Also can you go to your rails console and check if the record has indeed the saved description?

Comment: nunopolonia - I have provided the code for the view. However, I do not know how to check if the description has been saved. How do I do that?

Comment: in a terminal, run the command rails console, then get the last saved freq using freq = Freq.last. It will show you an hash of the record, and you can see if the description is saved.

Comment: Apparently, the description is 'nil'. Looks like it didn't save. What can be done from here?

Comment: The problem can be in two places, the form or the controller action saving your record. You should create a new record using the form, and then look at the development log, to see the parameters being sent, and if the record is being saved properly. If the description parameter is not being sent to the controller, the problem is in the form, if it's being sent but not saved, the problem is in the controller.

Comment: The problem is in the controller. I have updated the original post with the error I am receiving from the console. It's a "can't mass assign" error.

Comment: If you're using Rails3, you need to add "attr_accessible :description" to the Freq Model

Comment: I actually did a bit of searching before you responded, and this was, indeed, the answer I found. I'm actually on Rails 4, but this worked. Thank you very much for your help. Very much appreciated.

Comment: In Rails4 the parameter control passed from the model to the controller, so in the controller, you should have the "freq_params" function. There, it should be something like params.permit(:description). If it isn't, add it, and remove the attr_acessible line from the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails 4, the parameter validation was removed from the Model, and now lives in the Controller. So, the "attr_accessible" line isn't used in the model anymore.

From the line you gave from the controller, there is a freq_params function in your controller, that should be like this:

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def freq_params
  params.require(:freq).permit(:description)
end
```

If it's not, change it to this, and remove the attr_accessible line from the Freq Model.